# Conditionally format the same cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I will like the format the same cell in google sheet, to be more specific, any positive increase to the previous value (same cell) will turn green, and any negative decrease to the previous value (same cell) will turn red, for example:  if a have cell A2= 100, and I then change A2 to 90, I will like that cell to turn red, if I then change it to 95 it will turn green.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sheets will conditionally format based on a formula. For example you could use  `A2<100` or `A2>100` or `A2=90`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this problem with an helper column and a script like:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var currRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
var cell = sheet.getRange(currRow,2);
cell.setValue( e.oldValue);
}
```

See [this demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZvGX7yKVouhzcde55NY3yg5xbU8PyATjrbjBsqYJ9ag/edit?usp=sharing)

*note that this is just a quick example to refine with column checking*

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.